# Newer construct for width in XHTML?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xhtml

I built a table like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="20%">
            Nombre
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but I have a warning "Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'width' is considered outdated. A newer construct is recommended"

What is a Newer construct for width in XHTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `width` attribute for `<td>` has been **[deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#adef-width-TH)**.

You should replace the `width` attribute with the CSS `width` property:

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 20%;">
            Nombre
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use only CSS attributes:

```
<table style="width:100%; border:0px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20%;">
            Nombre
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```